# Email receiving service with Microsoft Graph API in spring boot/Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get  Mail folders (ex-inbox) using Microsoft Graph API in the spring boot backend. Could you please share the necessary steps and code snippet to develop this?